# Adding a new record to a database with java prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am creating a method to load in vales from an interface to create a new record in my database.

I have tried several methods and keep getting different errors.

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '939' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
    public boolean newStudent(String studentId, String name, String degreeScheme) throws SQLException 
{ 
    // Use SIMPLEDATASOURCE connection
```

Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'student_name = 'mark' degree_Scheme = 'cis'' at line 1

```
        try {
          conn.createStatement();
          PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement( "UPDATE student SET studentId = ?");
          stat.setString(1,studentId); // Use parameter 
          stat.executeUpdate(); // Execute prepared stat
         return stat.executeUpdate() == 1 ;

        }
    finally
    {
        // Close the connection
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the same studentId to all the students, and if the table has a primary key (studentId) is forbidden. I think you want to do an INSERT.

Comment: Was there a question? Or were you just giving a report on the status of your current development efforts?

Answer (score 1):

Was there a question in there somewhere?

```
Duplicate entry '939' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This indicates that you are either inserting a row or updating a row to have a PRIMARY KEY value that already exists in the table.  (The value of the column(s) making up the PRIMARY KEY *must* be UNIQUE on each row; no two rows can have the same value.)

This query:

```
UPDATE student SET studentId = ?
```

Is going to attempt to set the `studentId` column to the *same* value on *every* row.

We're guessing that `studentId` is defined as the PRIMARY KEY of the `student` table, and that the table contains more than one row. We'd expect the execution of this statement to throw a "duplicate key" exception, like the one you are reporting.